Mersenne prime numbers with Lua and LuaTeX
I had a table of Mersenne numbers. As I needed to do some more stuff with Mersenne numbers later on. I used Lua to capture the values from the table and then defined two  commands \mersennefromrange and \mersennefromrank. The table is shown partially in the image below and the output from mersennefromrank I am looking at suggestions how to improve the Lua code and the long table aesthetics. On the latter I am aware of booktabs, but this type of table reads better with the lines. The first term from the output from the rank is wrong, as I did not capture the primes. Next revision! Also hoping to do some actual calculations with PARI, use a batch file and see how far I can calculate these. With Lua I can calculate upto M31.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{amsmath} % needed fro \sp superscript
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}

  \hypersetup{colorlinks,%added
              linkcolor=blue,
              urlcolor=blue,
              filecolor=blue,
              citecolor=blue,
              raiselinks=true,
              linktoc=all,
}
\begin{document}

% Use LIST to store in an array the result of the calculation. As some numbers are very long they are split into
% left 16-numbers and right-16 numbers.
\begin{luacode}
 local Llist = Llist or {}
 local Rlist = Rlist or {}
 LIST = {Llist,Rlist}
 function Llist.insert(x)
   table.insert(Llist,{tostring(x),"-9"})
 end
 function Rlist.insert(x)
   table.insert(Rlist,{tostring(x),"-9"})
 end
\end{luacode}


 \def\store#1{
\directlua{
   local Llist = LIST[1]
   Llist.insert("#1")  
  }
   \textbf{#1} 
 }
 
\def\storei#1{
\directlua{
  local Rlist = LIST[2]
  Rlist.insert("#1")
  }
   \textcolor{blue}{#1} 
 }

\begingroup
\let\BF\textbf
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\def\L#1 {\href{https://oeis.org/#1}{#1}}
\begin{longtable}{|c|p{2cm}|c|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.7cm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3.7cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Rank}                                                %1   
& \textbf{2\textsuperscript{p}-1} \L A000043                 %2 
& \textbf{ OEIS A-number}                                    %3   
&Digits                                                      %4
&\BF{First 16-digits} \L A135613 , \L A138862 , \L A138864  
& \BF{\mbox{Last~16-digits}}  \L A080172 , \L A080173 , \L A138865 \\
\hline

%\textbf{A-number} & \textbf{\# of digits} & \textbf{A028335 First 16 digits} & %\textbf{A135613, A138862, A138864 Last 16 digits} \\ \hline
%\endfirsthead
%\hline
%\textbf{Rank} & \textbf{2\textsuperscript{p}-1} & \textbf{A000043 OEIS} & \textbf{A-number} & \textbf{\# of digits} & \textbf{A028335 First 16 digits} & \textbf{A135613, A138862, A138864 Last 16 digits} \\ \hline
%\endhead
1 & 2 & \L A000668 & 1 & \store{3} & \storei{3} \\ \hline
2 & 3 & \L A000668 & 1 & \store{7} & \storei{7} \\ \hline
3 & 5 & \L A000668 & 2 & \store{31} & \storei{31} \\ \hline
4 & 7 & \L A000668 & 3 & \store{127} & \storei{127} \\ \hline
5 & 13 & \L A000668 & 4 & \store{8191} & \storei{8191} \\ \hline
6 & 17 & \L A000668 & 6 & \store{131071} & \storei{131071} \\ \hline
7 & 19 & \L A000668 & 6 & \store{524287} & \storei{524287} \\ \hline
8 & 31 & \L A000668 & 10 & \store{2147483647} & \storei{2147483647} \\ \hline
9 & 61 & \L A000668 & 19 & \store{2305843009213693} & \storei{5843009213693951} \\ \hline
10 & 89 & \L A000668 & 27 & \store{6189700196426901} & \storei{2690137449562111} \\ \hline
11 & 107 & \L A000668, \L A169684 & 33 & \store{1622592768292133} & \storei{3391578010288127} \\ \hline
12 & 127 & \L A000668, \L A169681 & 39 & \store{1701411834604692} & \storei{7303715884105727} \\ \hline
13 & 521 & \L A000668, \L A169685 & 157 & \store{6864797660130609} & \storei{4028291115057151} \\ \hline
14 & 607 & \L A000668, \L A204063 & 183 & \store{5311379928167670} & \storei{5393219031728127} \\ \hline
15 & 1279 & \L A000668, \L A248931 & 386 & \store{1040793219466439} & \storei{0555703168729087} \\ \hline
16 & 2203 & \L A000668, \L A248932 & 664 & \store{1475979915214180} & \storei{9497686697771007} \\ \hline
17 & 2281 & \L A000668, \L A248933 & 687 & \store{4460875571837584} & \storei{3172418132836351} \\ \hline
18 & 3217 & \L A000668, \L A248934 & 969 & \store{2591170860132026} & \storei{0677362909315071} \\ \hline
19 & 4253 & \L A248935 & 1281 & \store{1907970075244390} & \storei{4687815350484991} \\ \hline
20 & 4423 & \L A248936 & 1332 & \store{2855425422282796} & \storei{1057902608580607} \\ \hline
21 & 9689 & \L A275977 & 2917 & \store{4782202788054612} & \storei{2696826225754111} \\ \hline
22 & 9941 & \L A275979 & 2993 & \store{3460882824908512} & \storei{6224883789463551} \\ \hline
23 & 11213 & \L A275980 & 3376 & \store{2814112013697373} & \storei{1476087696392191} \\ \hline
24 & 19937 & \L A275981 & 6002 & \store{4315424797388162} & \storei{1539030968041471} \\ \hline
25 & 21701 & \L A275982 & 6533 & \store{4486791661190433} & \storei{0828353511882751} \\ \hline
26 & 23209 & \L A275983 & 6987 & \store{4028741157789887} & \storei{3355523779264511} \\ \hline
27 & 44497 & \L A275984 & 13395 & \store{8545098243036338} & \storei{7686961011228671} \\ \hline
28 & 86243 &  & 25962 & \store{5369279955027563} & \storei{7021709433438207} \\ \hline
29 & 110503 &  & 33265 & \store{5219283133417550} & \storei{1621083465515007} \\ \hline
30 & 132049 &  & 39751 & \store{5127402762693207} & \storei{8578455730061311} \\ \hline
31 & 216091 &  & 65050 & \store{7460931030646613} & \storei{6204103815528447} \\ \hline
32 & 756839 &  & 227832 & \store{1741359068200870} & \storei{3793328544677887} \\ \hline
33 & 859433 &  & 258716 & \store{1294981256042076} & \storei{4267243500142591} \\ \hline
34 & 1257787 &  & 378632 & \store{4122457736214286} & \storei{7188976089366527} \\ \hline
35 & 1398269 &  & 420921 & \store{8147175644125730} & \storei{2025868451315711} \\ \hline
36 & 2976221 &  & 895932 & \store{6233400762485786} & \storei{6256743729201151} \\ \hline
37 & 3021377 &  & 909526 & \store{1274116830300933} & \storei{2631973024694271} \\ \hline
38 & 6972593 &  &  2098960 & \store{4370757441270813} & \storei{6526142924193791} \\ \hline
39 & 13466917 & \L A089065 & 4053946 & \store{9249477380067013} & \storei{3855470256259071} \\ \hline
40 & 20996011 & \L A089578 & 6320430 & \store{1259768954503301} & \storei{4065762855682047} \\ \hline
41 & 24036583 &  & 7235733 & \store{2994104294041571} & \storei{6921882733969407} \\ \hline
42 & 25964951 &  & 7816230 & \store{1221646300612779} & \storei{3257280577077247} \\ \hline
43 & 30402457 & \L A117853 & 9152052 & \store{3154164756188460} & \storei{4297411652943871} \\ \hline
44 & 32582657 &  & 9808358 & \store{1245750260153694} & \storei{2880154053967871} \\ \hline
45 & 37156667 &  & 11185272 & \store{2022544068909773} & \storei{0265022308220927} \\ \hline
46 & 42643801 &  & 12837064 & \store{1698735164527416} & \storei{1954765562314751} \\ \hline
47 & 43112609 & \L A193864 & 12978189 & \store{3164702693302559} & \storei{2181166697152511} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\def\mersennefromrange#1#2{
\directlua{
local Llist,Rlist=LIST[1],LIST[2]
for k=#1,#2  do
  tex.sprint(1,k,  " = ".. Llist[k][1]..".."..Rlist[k][1] )
  tex.print("\\par")
end  
}}

\def\mersennefromrank#1{
\(
\luadirect{
 local Llist,Rlist=LIST[1],LIST[2]
local power= '\\mathrm{rank} = #1 = '..'2\\sp{#1-1}'.. '=' .. Llist[#1][1].."\\dots"..Rlist[#1][1]
tex.print(power)
}
\)
}

%% testing 

\mersennefromrange{1}{47}

\bigskip

{\LARGE
\mersennefromrank{47}
}
\end{document}


\usepackage{amsmath} % needed fro \sp superscript  you don't need any package for \sp

Have you seen https://www.ntg.nl/maps/42/09.pdf? Page 5 demonstrates almost exactly what you're looking for.

@MaxChernoff  thanks. Your comment came just in time. I just wrote the skeleton for it this morning! I will read the article and have a nice day.

@MaxChernoff  My approach is much simpler as I do not use Lua bindings avoiding compilations. I just issue terminal commands from within the document and LuaTeX  and just print a message on a first run, to give time for the process to finish. Then check for the file in the second run and rinse-repeat. Not as elegant as the one described in the article...

I know this is a bit (quite) off-topic as it does not use luatex, but there are ways to do computation in TeX without Lua: bigintcalc, apnum, xfp (which I think is part of LaTeX nowadays), ..., others probably.  I tried with xintexpr.  I did the compilation with pdflatex, but it would be the same with lualatex.  I think one can use simply etex, or pdftex, but I used the LaTeX format for booktabs package.
Much to my embarrassment I realized after posting my first "solution" that it was not needed to compute the Mersenne primes with all their digits in order to fill up your table.  Please pardon that my math education is way back in the past and I had forgotten about logarithm/powers.
Second solution (full table)
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{colorlinks,%added
              linkcolor=blue,
              urlcolor=blue,
              filecolor=blue,
              citecolor=blue,
              raiselinks=true,
              linktoc=all,
}

\newcommand\LOEIS[1]{\href{https://oeis.org/#1}{#1}}

\makeatletter % for \@namedef/\@nameuse of LaTeX
% Do all computations in preamble
\xintSetDigits{24}% work with 24 digits floating point precision

%%%%%%%%%%%% after some digging in xintexpr documentation
%% Modular exponentiation
%%  "2.11.3. Examples of recursive definitions"
\xintdefiifunc powmod_a(x, m, n) := isone(m)?
   % m=1, return x modulo n
   { x/:n }
   % m > 1 test if odd or even and do recursive call 
   { odd(m)? { x*sqr(powmod_a(x, m//2, n)) /: n }
             {   sqr(powmod_a(x, m//2, n)) /: n }
   }
;
\xintdefiifunc powmod(x, m, n) := (m)?{powmod_a(x, m, n)}{1};
%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Prepare the data
\def\temp{0}
\xintForpair#1#2 in {
( 2 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 3 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 5 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 7 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 13 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 17 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 19 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 31 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 61 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 89 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 107 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A169684}}),
( 127 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A169681}}),
( 521 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A169685}}),
( 607 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A204063}}),
( 1279 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248931}}),
( 2203 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248932}}),
( 2281 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248933}}),
( 3217 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248934}}),
( 4253 , \LOEIS{A248935}),
( 4423 , \LOEIS{A248936}),
( 9689 , \LOEIS{A275977}),
( 9941 , \LOEIS{A275979}),
( 11213 , \LOEIS{A275980}),
( 19937 , \LOEIS{A275981}),
( 21701 , \LOEIS{A275982}),
( 23209 , \LOEIS{A275983}),
( 44497 , \LOEIS{A275984}),
( 86243 ,  ),
( 110503 ,  ),
( 132049 ,  ),
( 216091 ,  ),
( 756839 ,  ),
( 859433 ,  ),
( 1257787 ,  ),
( 1398269 ,  ),
( 2976221 ,  ),
( 3021377 ,  ),
( 6972593 ,  ),
( 13466917 , \LOEIS{A089065}),
( 20996011 , \LOEIS{A089578}),
( 24036583 ,  ),
( 25964951 ,  ),
( 30402457 , \LOEIS{A117853}),
( 32582657 ,  ),
( 37156667 ,  ),
( 42643801 ,  ),
( 43112609 , \LOEIS{A193864})% <<<--- do not use ending comma here! (bug of xintfor?)
}\do{%
  \edef\temp{\the\numexpr\temp+1}%
  %
  % Exponent column
  % ---------------
  \xintdefiivar p_\temp := #1;%
  %
  % OEIS column
  % -----------
  \@namedef{\temp_OEIS}{#2}%
  %
  % Computation of float approximation (24 digits mantissa)
  % -------------------------------------------------------
  \xintdeffloatvar M#1 := 2^#1 - 1;%
  %
  % Number of digits
  % ----------------
  % We use the ilog10() function
  % It returns the exponent e such that 10^e <= x < 10^(e+1)
  \xintdeffloatvar M#1_nbdigits := ilog10(M#1) + 1;%
  %
  % First 16 digits
  % ---------------
  % This required **quite a lot** of digging in xintexpr documentation...
  % ... not fully sure it does what is hoped for in all cases.
  \xintdefiivar M#1_firstdigits := \xintKeepUnbraced{16}{\xintRaw{\xintfloateval{M#1}}};%
  %
  % Last 16 digits
  % --------------
  % We use modular exponentiation.
  % math note: it is not possible for the last 16 digits of 2^p to all
  % be zero, because the last digit can not be zero... hence substracting
  % 1 is ok.
  \xintdefiivar M#1_lastdigits := powmod(2,#1,10^16) -1;%
}

\newcommand\MTableRow[1]{%
% rank
   #1 &
% exponent
   \xintiieval{p_#1} &
% OEIS
   \@nameuse{#1_OEIS} &
% nb of digits
% was not sure it would work, but it does!
% it would have been easier to index by the rank #1, not by exponent
% I had **lots** of trouble to get this to print as an integer
% It insisted on using floating point notation !
% Finally I found \xintNumerator
   \xintNumerator{\xintfloateval{M\xintiieval{p_#1}_nbdigits}} &
% first 16 digits
   \xintiieval{M\xintiieval{p_#1}_firstdigits} &
% last 16 digits
% ATTENTION! we must use a trick to show leading zeroes
   \xintifboolexpr
      {M\xintiieval{p_#1}_nbdigits>16}
      {\xintTrim{1}{\xintiieval{10^16 + M\xintiieval{p_#1}_lastdigits}}}
      {\xintiieval{M\xintiieval{p_#1}_lastdigits}} \\
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{clcclr}
\toprule
    Rank&$p$ ($P=2^p-1$)&OEIS A-number&Digits&First 16 digits&Last 16 digits\\
\midrule
\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{47}}\do{\MTableRow{#1}}
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table of Mersenne Primes}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Output:

First solution (limited to up to M_44497 because computes fully all digits internally...)
The solution does not have the OEIS references because I did not find easily a reference giving them.  From the xinttools part of xintexpr manual, there is an \xintForpair #1#2 in {(2, A000668), (3, A000668), ...} which could be used.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}

\xintglobaldefstrue

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{clcclr}
\toprule
    Rank&$p$ ($P=2^p-1$)&OEIS A-number&Digits&First 16 digits&Last 16 digits\\
\midrule
\xintdefiivar rank:=0;\xintFor #1 in {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 
    107, 127, 521, 607, 1279, 2203, 2281, 3217, 4253, 4423, 9689, 9941}\do
{\xintdefiivar rank:=rank+1;\xintiieval{rank}&
 \xintdefiivar P:=2^#1-1;#1&
 ---
 &\xintNthElt{0}{\xintiieval{P}}
 &\xintKeepUnbraced{16}{\xintiieval{P}}
 &\xintKeepUnbraced{-16}{\xintiieval{P}}\\
}
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table of Mersenne Primes}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Using the data from the OP edited question I have added the OEIS number for the computed range:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\LOEIS[1]{\href{https://oeis.org/#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\xintglobaldefstrue

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{clcclr}
\toprule
    Rank&$p$ ($P=2^p-1$)&OEIS A-number&Digits&First 16 digits&Last 16 digits\\
\midrule
\xintdefiivar rank:=0;%
%\xintFor #1 in {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 
%    107, 127, 521, 607, 1279, 2203, 2281, 3217, 4253, 4423, 9689, 9941}\do
\xintForpair #1#2 in {
( 2 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 3 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 5 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 7 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 13 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 17 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 19 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 31 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 61 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 89 , \LOEIS{A000668}),
( 107 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A169684}}),
( 127 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A169681}}),
( 521 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A169685}}),
( 607 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A204063}}),
( 1279 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248931}}),
( 2203 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248932}}),
( 2281 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248933}}),
( 3217 , {\LOEIS{A000668}, \LOEIS{A248934}}),
( 4253 , \LOEIS{A248935}),
( 4423 , \LOEIS{A248936}),
( 9689 , \LOEIS{A275977}),
( 9941 , \LOEIS{A275979})}
\do
{\xintdefiivar rank:=rank+1;\xintiieval{rank}&
 \xintdefiivar P:=2^#1-1;#1&
 #2
 &\xintNthElt{0}{\xintiieval{P}}
 &\xintKeepUnbraced{16}{\xintiieval{P}}
 &\xintKeepUnbraced{-16}{\xintiieval{P}}\\
}
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table of Mersenne Primes}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}


The xintexpr doc says things about thousands of digits being some sort of maximum so I don't expect one can add more than a few rows to the displayed table which goes up to rank 22, but rank 26 Mersenne prime has 6987 digits so it may be very lengthy for xintexpr (untested).
edit: I have now tested and could go up to rank 27 i.e. 2^44497-1 which has 13395 digits.  Total ompilation time will depend on CPU, probably around 20s for most.
I also found what appears to be a bug of \xintForpair that it seems it falls into infinite loop if the (a,b), (c,d), ... list ends with  a comma after the last closing parenthesis...
( 9689 , \LOEIS{A275977}),
( 9941 , \LOEIS{A275979}),
( 11213 , \LOEIS{A275980}),
( 19937 , \LOEIS{A275981}),
( 21701 , \LOEIS{A275982}),
( 23209 , \LOEIS{A275983}),
( 44497 , \LOEIS{A275984})%  NO COMMA HERE!!!! (BUG?)
}%



Thanks, for a very interesting solution.

I have added an approach which does not go via the exact computation of the Mersenne numbers with all their digits... this allows to cover the full range.

To get the first 16 digits, the Mersenne prime is computed as a float with 24-digits mantissa, then only first 16 digits are kept.  The result could be wrong if actual value of Mersenne prime is <first 16 digits>999999997<more digits.  Because then the float rouning to 24 digits will have increased by 1unit the 16th one and end with 8 zeros.  Testing if the 24 digits end with 8 zeroes is no solution either because it could be that the 8 zeroes are really there... But I am not too much worried and anyhow all values I checked match your data!!

Thanks, I read the xintexpr manual this morning and is impressive. Is it your package? As to accuracy when you move onto floats, I would just use Oberdiek's trick. From memory I think it was in his bigint package, he said about primes, since you are going to cache the results in any case you might as well store them in an array and retrieve them as you wish avoiding the calculation :)

@yannisl No, I think the xintexpr maintainer is not on this site; I know well their other package etoc and have answered I think between 5 and 10 etoc question and I never saw their author here...about "Oberdiek trick" I think you are quite right and I see now reading your question better you asked more for matters of tables etc..., and I unduly focused on computations (because you mentioned being able to go to M_31 with Lua) ; I was expecting some answer using multi-precision library which I think is available in LuaTeX, but beyond my knowledge!

Thanks. There are BigNum libraries in Lua, pretty much as any other BigNum library using school book type arithmetic.
